# Calculating acreage using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

What is the expression to calculate an acreage in USA ? I am aware that there is a geometry calculate but when you convert raster to polygon it doesn't do it's job and I have to use the field calculator to manual it.

I am writing a model builder and in it I have tools for Add field and calculate  them for 83 datasets.

Comment: the automated "shape_area" field exists with geodatabase, but not with shapefiles. Also, the unit of the area is the same as the reference system of the data.

Answer (score 12):

In ModelBuilder, drop in the [Calculate Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) tool (under *Data Management | Fields* toolbox) and use the expression `!shape.area@acres!` (make sure Expression Type is `PYTHON` or `PYTHON_9.3`.)

Or, in ArcPy: `arcpy.CalculateField_management(YourFeature, Field, "!shape.area@acres!", "PYTHON", "")`

It's possible to use a wide range of units for both area and length calculations this way:

> Shape and length properties of the geometry field can be modified with unit types expressed with an @ sign.
>
> Areal unit of measure keywords: ACRES | ARES | HECTARES | SQUARECENTIMETERS | SQUAREDECIMETERS | SQUAREINCHES | SQUAREFEET | SQUAREKILOMETERS | SQUAREMETERS | SQUAREMILES | SQUAREMILLIMETERS | SQUAREYARDS | SQUAREMAPUNITS | UNKNOWN
>
> Linear unit of measure keywords: CENTIMETERS | DECIMALDEGREES | DECIMETERS | FEET | INCHES | KILOMETERS | METERS | MILES | MILLIMETERS | NAUTICALMILES | POINTS | UNKNOWN | YARDS

Answer (score 5):

You may include this python expression in your field calculator tool:

```
!shape.area@acres!
```

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000

Comment: Does anyone know the calculation to convert square feet to acres, supposing someone wanted to do this in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

in the field calculator ([CalculateField tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) in model builder), you can use the following expression.

!shape.area@ACRES!

Answer (score 0):

The actual formula or expression depends on your CRS measurement units, since acres is one unit and CRS units can vary - degrees, meters, feet, etc. Assuming you are in a projection, you'll probably have feet or meters.

1 acre = 43,560 square feet = 4046.85642 square meters

As radouxju mentions, shapefiles don't automatically track shape area, but feature classes in geodatabases do - only in the CRS units though. As the other answers suggest, using Field Calculator with a function is the only way to do this 'automatically' in ModelBuilder since the Calculate Geometry tool can't be accessed from there.

Comment: when you convert raster or image to polygon, does it takes from the pixels from that raster or image ? Is there a way to smooth it a little bit ? How do you match the polygon with the image ? I am thinking it's not possible but....

Comment: @PROBERT [The tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000) gives you a choice. If you smooth it, it of course won't match exactly - that's just the nature of the difference between a raster and a vector representation of data.